# Every polynomial of the form: $(x+m+a)(x+m-a)(x+m+b)(x-m-b)$ where ....

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials

Does every polynomial of the form: $(x+m+a)(x+m-a)(x+m+b)(x-m-b)$ where: $a \neq b+m $ and $a,b,m \in\ \Bbb R $ have unique absolute and local minimums, and one local maximum?

If not, is there a general expression for a fourth degree polynomial with the condition that it will have unique absolute and local minimums, one local maximum, and four roots not counting multiplicity?

It seems that when the function is not symmetric the conditions are met and it appears that these conditions I provided ensure it is not. I just can't figure out why and would love some food for thought.

Thank you,
Julian

Comment: If we take $a = b = 0$ and $m = 2$ (say), then the polynomial is $(x+2)^{3}(x-2)$, which has no local max and one local min at $x = 1$. Not sure what you mean by absolute extrema, since you haven't specified an interval of consideration.

Comment: Thank you, I need a general equation for a quartic poly with four roots, and unique absolute and local minimums, and one local maximum?

Comment: How about: $(x-\frac{5a}{6}) (x-\frac{a}{2}) (\frac{a}{3}+\frac{2}{a}+x) (\frac{3a}{2}+x)$ where: $a\neq 0$